# Ruby look-behind with cyrillic and phrase 'magist'

Tags: ruby, regex, negative-lookbehind

I would like to strip all urls except my site.

I wrote regex like

```
 r = 'https?:\/\/[\da-z\.-]+(?<!MY_DOMAIN)\.[a-z\.]{2,6}\/?[^\s\]\[\<\>]*'
 e = Regexp.new(e, Regexp::IGNORECASE | Regexp::MULTILINE), '***'
 text.gsub e, '***'
```

it's work if 'text'variable haven't Cyrillic symbols and 'r' variable haven't 'magist' - string.
If 'text' have Cyrillic then i got a error.

Examples:

```
r = 'https?:\/\/[\da-z\.-]+(?<!magist)\.[a-z\.]{2,6}\/?[^\s\]\[\<\>]*'
e = Regexp.new(r, Regexp::IGNORECASE | Regexp::MULTILINE)
text = 'Text https://magist.net/ text https://google.com text text'
text.gsub e, '***'
=> "Text https://magist.net/ text *** text text"
```

add 'тест' to any position

```
text = 'Text https://magist.net/ text https://google.com text тест text'
text.gsub e, '***'
=> RegexpError: invalid pattern in look-behind: /https?:\/\/[\da-z\.-]+(?<!magist)\.[a-z\.]{2,6}\/?[^\s\]\[\<\>]*/mi
```

Replace 'magist' to 'magiat' (s => a) then work fine with Cyrilic

```
r = 'https?:\/\/[\da-z\.-]+(?<!magiat)\.[a-z\.]{2,6}\/?[^\s\]\[\<\>]*'
e = Regexp.new(r, Regexp::IGNORECASE | Regexp::MULTILINE)
text.gsub e, '***'
=> "Text *** text *** text тест text"
text = 'Text https://magiat.net/ text https://google.com text тест text'
=> "Text https://magiat.net/ text https://google.com text тест text"
```

If i replace regex so:

```
r = 'https?:\/\/(?!magis)[\da-z\.-]+\.[a-z\.]{2,6}\/?[^\s\]\[\<\>]*'
```

It's work fine to all strings.

Why look-behind don't work with Cyrillic and 'magist' string? :)

Comment: What ruby version are you on? I have no issues running your code: everything runs smoothly.

Comment: ruby -v
ruby 2.4.1p111 (2017-03-22 revision 58053) [x86_64-darwin16]

Comment: Huh `darwin`. There might be some problem induced, or it’s MacOS who screws things up as she always does. The code above runs without a glitch even on Ruby 1.9 on my local.

Comment: thank you! I will use the code on Debian. I hope it will work :)

Comment: Seems to be related: https://bugs.ruby-lang.org/issues/13671